# Angular2: ngOnInit() not called after router.navigate

Tags: angular, authentication, angular-routing, angular-services

I am trying to redirect the user back to the login screen if our frontend angular application loses connection to the backend server, but something is broken.

A normal logout is triggered from my NavBarComponent by hitting logout:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.me = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser') || 'null');
}

logout() {
   this._authenticationService.logout();
}
```

This in turn calls the authentication service logout function():

```
logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this._userService.announceLoginUpdate(false);
}
```

My NavBarComponent is subscribing to updateUserStatus$ and will redirect to login:

```
this.subscription = _userService.updateUserStatus$.subscribe( loggedIn => {

      this.loggedIn = loggedIn;

      if(this.loggedIn) {   
        console.log('NavbarComponent, 1');      
        this.me = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser') || 'null');
      } else {
        console.log('NavbarComponent, 2');
        this.me = null;
        //this._ref.markForCheck();
        //this._ref.detectChanges();
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }

    });
```

This all works, but I also want the frontend to detect, if it has lost its connection to the backend (backend-crash, restart, etc). So if the frontend receives a 403 from the backend, it will try to do new backend request to /user/me and if that also returns a 403, it will redirect to the login screen. (that is the basic scenario so far)

I have created an error.service with a handleError function that will get called if the frontend receives an error when communicating with the backend:

```
handleError(error: any) {
this._authenticationService.isUserLoggedIn().subscribe(response=> { 
        console.log('isUserLoggedIn, User is logged in', response.statusCode);      

    }, error => { 
        console.log('isUserLoggedIn, User is not logged in', error.statusCode);            

        this._authenticationService.logout();

    });

return Observable.throw("500 internal server error");
```

}

This does NOT work correctly. It catches the error correctly (gets a 403 from the backend), and calls the this._authenticationService.logout() which in turns removes the user and forces the update that the NavBarComponent is subscribing, which then redirects to the login page.

However the login page renders the login component with no text, no model binding and the login component ngOnInit is not getting called. The LoginComponent does not seem "instantiated".

My LoginComponent ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log("LoginComponent ngOnInit");
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
}
```

When a normal user logout is performed the ngOnInit is called and the component works.

Does anyone know what is going wrong? It is the same code that gets executed, just from different places (one from the component and one from a service)

I have attached screenshots of the login page when normal user logout is performed and from the "forced" service logout.

[How it should NOT look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2u14.png)

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baEEB.png)

Comment: Are you sure ngOnInit isn't firing in your login component?  Have you debugged it or outputted a console statement from it?

Comment: Yes, I have a console.log statement in the ngOnInit. It is not firing.. I edited the above to show my login component

Comment: Hmm, the only times I've had issues around ngOninit not firing have been when the router navigates to the current route with differening params.  In that case ngOnInit doesn't fire and you'd need to subscribe to the route.params collection and watch for changes to do your initialization code.  But it doesn't sound like that is what is happening in your case...

Comment: Yes it is very strange indeed. In addition if I try and fill in the login form (on the broken login page) and click submit the LoginComponent reports that the model.username and model.password is "undefined". So there is clearly a disconnect. "Seems" like the angular part "died" and you only get the HTML without the engine.